# For $x+y+z=3,$ prove $\frac{1}{x^2+4}+\frac{1}{y^2+4}+\frac{1}{z^2+4}\le \frac{3}{5}.$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw, convexity-inequality, mixing-variables

Let $x,y,z\ge 0: x+y+z=3.$ Prove that$$\frac{1}{x^2+4}+\frac{1}{y^2+4}+\frac{1}{z^2+4}\le \frac{3}{5}.$$
Here is just my thought progress.
I set $0\le xy+yz+zx=q\le 3; 0\le r=xyz\le 1.$ After full expanding, I get $$7q^2-16q+3r^2-42r+24\ge 0.$$
From now, I tried to use $pqr$ method but failed.

I hope you give me a advice to continue my approach. By the way, if you found others idea, please post it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: *Very* similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3878235/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3404382/42969.

Comment: Tangent line method help

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of total symmetry around the line $L\to p = \lambda(1,1,1)'$. In cases like that we can choose a plane $P$ which contains $L$ and study to solve the proposed problem. Taking $P\to p\cdot \vec n=0$ suffices to choose $\vec n = (1,-1,0)'$ or $x-y=0$. so we follow with: prove

$$
\cases{
\frac{2}{x^2+4}+\frac{1}{z^2+4}\le \frac 35\\
2x+z = 3
}
$$

which is trivially solved as $\max_{x,z}\frac{2}{x^2+4}+\frac{1}{z^2+4}$ s. t $\cases{x\ge 0\\ z\ge 0\\ 2x+z = 3}$ .

Comment: Nice using LM! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.**

I continued the original proposer's approach.

Indeed, we will prove a quadratic polynomial of $r$
$$f(r)=3r^2-42r+7q^2-16q+24\ge 0.$$
Notice that $f'(r)=6r-42<0,$ hence $f(r)$ is decreasing.
We can use $$r \le \dfrac{q^2(p^2-q)}{2p(2p^2-3q)}=\dfrac{q^2(9-q)}{18(6-q)}.\tag {*}$$
Id est, it's enough to prove $$7q^2-16q+3\left(\dfrac{q^2(9-q)}{18(6-q)}\right)^2-42\dfrac{q^2(9-q)}{18(6-q)}+24\ge 0,$$which is equivalent to
$$\frac{(q - 3) (q^5 - 15 q^4 + 540 q^3 - 5400 q^2 + 20736 q - 31104)}{108 (q - 6)^2}\ge 0.$$
The last inequality is true for all $0\le q\le 3.$

We end proof here. Equality holds at $x=y=z=1.$

*Remark.* The inequality $(*)$ can be solved by AM-GM based on the following indentity$$(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2=p^2q^2-4q^3+2p(9q-2p^2)r-27r^2.$$

Comment: I'll add another solution soon.

Comment: Yes, thank you for sharing to us.

Comment: @TATAbox How did you prove $(*)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+4}.$

Thus, $$f''(x)=\frac{6x^2-8}{(x^2+4)^3}\leq0,$$ for $0\leq x\leq\frac{x+y+z}{3}=1.$

Thus, by the Vasc's LCF Theorem it's enough to prove our inequality for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=x$ and $z=3-2x$, where $0\leq0\leq\frac{3}{2}.$

Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{2}{x^2+4}+\frac{1}{(3-2x)^2+5}\leq\frac{3}{5}$$ or
$$(x-1)^2(2x^2-2x+1)\geq0$$ and we are done.

About LCF see here: https://cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/VasileCirtoaje.pdf p.143

Comment: +1. I see that $f'(w^3)<0$ and we can use $uvw.$

Comment: @TATA box I also found this solution. Post it!

Comment: I will find another. It is better if you post $uvw$ proof.

Comment: @TATA box I see also three ways. :) Post something and I'll add.

Comment: I agree. Hope I will learn more from you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Let $z=\max\{x,y,z\}$ and $f(x,y,z)=\frac{3}{5}-\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^2+4}$.

Thus,   $z\geq1$, $x+y\leq2$ and by AM-GM $$f(x,y,z)-f\left(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x+y}{2},z\right)=\frac{8}{(x+y)^2+14}-\frac{1}{x^2+4}-\frac{1}{y^2+4}=$$
$$=\frac{(x-y)^2(8-x^2-4xy-y^2)}{((x+y)^2+16)(x^2+4)(y^2+4)}=\frac{(x-y)^2(8-(x+y)^2-2xy)}{((x+y)^2+16)(x^2+4)(y^2+4)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(x-y)^2\left(8-(x+y)^2-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}\right)}{((x+y)^2+16)(x^2+4)(y^2+4)}\geq\frac{2(x-y)^2}{((x+y)^2+16)(x^2+4)(y^2+4)}\geq0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for equality case of two variables, which for $y=x$ gives $$(x-1)^2(2x^2-2x+1)\geq0.$$

Comment: +1 Nice MV using!